# Where a route-map 'set' command writes a tag value?

Tags: cisco, route-map

Where a cisco-router writes a tag value when I use a 'set tag' command in a route-map? For example:

```
route-map TO_XXX permit 10
 match ip address TO_XXX
 set tag 99
```

Is it saved in IP-packet? In which field? How a next router gets this `99` for comparing with `match tag`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tags are advertised by the routing protocol, not in the IP packet.  In both OSPF and EIGRP, there is a tag field in the route advertisements (LSA for OSPF, external TLV for EIGRP).  So neighboring routers learn the tags as they learn the prefixes.